# command in for loop behaves differently (Batch file)

Tags: batch-file, warnings

I'm running a command in a batch file[Just for info: this command runs a python script which generates different outputs]
The code is as follows:

```
:meshfunc
echo "starting command"
echo "!inst_dir!runME.bat -parameter1 !parameter2! !parameter1v! -script pythonscript.py"
echo start_time=!time!
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"!inst_dir!runME.bat -parameter1 !parameter2! !parameter1v! -script pythonscript.py"') DO (
    set cmdline=%%i
    echo currentENDline=!cmdline!
)
EXIT /B 0
```

The output of the script is:
[image]

PS: I have stripped the output lines for obvious reasons, but they shouldn't matter here

So my questions is :
If i run the same command without a for loop , it will complete in maybe 30 sec without the warning at the end.
However, if I run it inside a for loop, it takes much longer about 3 mins and gives the warning at the end
Why am I'm getting the Warning at the end as shown. Why is this happening?

Comment: I would suggest using `CALL` for `runME.bat`.

Comment: I tried this.In this case what happens is the terminal gets stuck infinitely after calling that command...the command gets completed still it gets stuck infinitely at that line

Answer (score 0):

Because `for /F` execute the command enclosed in parentheses and store all its output in a temporary disk file until the command ends; after that, it start to repeatedly execute the group of commands. In this way, if the output is very large, the temporary file needs to grow several times and such a process takes some time... It should be faster to redirect the output to a disk file and then process such a file with `for /F`:

```
:meshfunc
echo "starting command"
echo "!inst_dir!runME.bat -parameter1 !parameter2! !parameter1v! -script pythonscript.py"
echo start_time=!time!
call "!inst_dir!runME.bat" -parameter1 !parameter2! !parameter1v! -script pythonscript.py > output.txt
for /F "delims=" %%i IN (output.txt) DO (
    set cmdline=%%i
    echo currentENDline=!cmdline!
)
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: thank.It answers my question.I had tired logging to a temp file.the problem with this is I get "File access denied" error in this case.[Strangely I have noticed the output is flushed only when I refresh/access the folder in which the temp log file is located.Not sure on this part though. So i entirely scrapped this idea of logging output to a temp file] How do I ensure entire output of the command is flushed to the temp log file before the successive script starts accessing it ( Time is varying here for the script to complete..it depends on the task..it varies from mins to an entire day) –

Comment: Well, this is an entirely different matter, so I suggest you to post a new question for it... May I ask you to accept this answer?

Comment: sorry? Its a partly answer of an alternative way to accomplish the same task. FYI: requote-"...I had tired logging to a temp...".Notice the 'had'. No hard feelings , but as you said - if this was the answer, the main question I asked today would never have been asked by me today. Clear enough?

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow your last comment. IMHO the question is very clear: _Why a command that complete in maybe 30 sec takes much longer, about 3 mins, when it is executed in a `for /F` loop?_, and my answer is also very clear. I don't understand if you want not an answer to this question, or if you want the answer to a not posted question. Sorry, but I am not a mind reader... **`:/`**

Comment: OK well I gotta admit my post very first post(-the question) doesn't 'explicitly' ask for the solution to avoid the warning(and 3 mins wait time instead of the normal 30 secs for the script to work), because I believe the full answer lies in the "solution " and not just the reason. So apologies, can we have the solution part, now that we are done with the reason part of the answer?

Comment: The solution to **this question** is clearly described in **my answer**: _redirect the output to a disk file and then process such a file with for /F_. Please, note that the comments are _not_ questions! (they are comments). To be clearer, **this comment**: "How do I ensure entire output of the command is flushed to the temp log file before the successive script starts accessing it" is totally unrelated to the topic of **this question**. Clear enough?

Comment: I don't want to keep repeating but sorry your answer only partially helps..I'm still.stuck with moving forward with my task.. which is moving ahead with executing that python script inside batch file without any warning or file access denied error.sry but I seriously want to no more discuss on the definition of comment/answer/the accuracy of my org question as I think I have clarified it enough in the so called comments.thnx